# Field formula for customer health score

Tags: formula-field

I'm wondering why this formula isn't working and was hoping for some help, as I think I'm missing something small. I'm trying to translate a numeric health score into colors based on ranges in a formula field.

```
IF(
    RecordType.Name <> "Customer", 
    "",
    IF(
        ISNULL (Product_Usage_Health_Score__c ),
        IF(
            Product_Usage_Health_Score__c <= 0.5, 
            "Red", 
            "ND"
        ),
        IF(
            Product_Usage_Health_Score__c  > 0.5  || Product_Usage_Health_Score__c  < 0.7, 
            "Yellow", 
            "ND"
        ),
        IF(
            Product_Usage_Health_Score__c  >= 0.7, 
            "Green", 
            "ND"
        )
    )
)
```

Error: "Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'; Expected 3, received 4

Thank you for the help!

Comment: In general, if you're getting an error (and you should be getting an error here), you should include the entirety of the error message. Trying to paraphrase or otherwise shorten the error usually means that you just cut out important information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Derek - updated!

Answer (score 0):

The issues I see here are:

- It looks like you forgot to use `NOT()` with `ISNULL (Product_Usage_Health_Score__c )`. You only want to try to assign a color if that field is *not null*
- When you're checking for if a number is in a range, you need to use `AND()` or `&&`, not `||` (because 0.8 would be > 0.5, which would get you into the "Yellow" case if you use `||`)
- You haven't composed the `IF()`s together correctly

The `IF()` function takes 3 parameters (only 3, and they're all required)
`IF(<condition>, <expression if true>, <expression if false>)`

The way you've structured the `Product_Usage_Health_Score__c` part of this formula looks like
`IF(<condition>, <expression if true>, <expression if false>, <another expression>)`

Instead, you need to continue nesting `IF()` functions inside either the `<expression if true>` or `<expression if false>` parts. Also, if you have an `IF()` that checks if `Product_Usage_Health_Score__c >= 0.7` and that check returns `false` (getting you into the `<expression if false>` part), then you don't need to explicitly check for `Product_Usage_Health_Score__c < 0.7`. It is guaranteed to be `< 0.7` by virtue of it not being `>= 0.7`

So all said and done, the inner part of your formula should look like

```
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Product_Usage_Health_Score__c)),
    IF(
        Product_Usage_Health_Score__c >= 0.7,
        "Green",
        IF(
            /* If we get here, the score is guaranteed to be < 0.7 */
            /* There is no need to explicitly check for that
            Product_Usage_Health_Score__c >= 0.5,
            "Yellow",
            /* Likewise, if we get here, the score is guaranteed to be < 0.5 */
            "Red"
        )
    ),
    "ND"
)
```

Assuming that "ND" stands for "No Data"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!